# Crosshair in brush tip is off-centre

Tags: adobe-photoshop

My cross-hair and brush tip are misaligned. The crosshair is near the bottom right of the brush tip, and any changes are based on this crosshair (ignoring the brush tip).

[image]

Very frustrating as working on pixel art. How can I reset this so that the crosshair is in the middle?

Answer (score 1):

Found this out by digging around the photoshop settings. Apparently I accidently chose another brush preset - oops...

[image: Centred crosshair: preset 1]
[image: Off-centre crosshair: preset 2]